# How to Handle Missing Columns In Spotfire Visualizations

Tags: expression, boxplot, spotfire

I created a dashboard in Spotfire which pulls unpivoted data from an SQL query to a data table. The data table is then pivoted based on the number of unique values in a particular column. I have a box plot visualization which is linked to this data table and displays several columns from the table. The problem is that in some of the data queries, not all of the columns will exist. If one column is missing, none of the data is displayed. Instead, Spotfire returns the message "Could not find column: 'column name'". How can I make the visualization still plot the remaining columns that do exist in the table in these cases where one or more of the columns might be missing?

EDIT:
I wrote this script and assigned it to a document property to be executed every time the document property changes value. The only problem now is that there's something wrong with my If statements. Only the final else: statement is returned even if the previous statements are true.

```
import Spotfire.Dxp.Data.DataTable
from Spotfire.Dxp.Application.Visuals import VisualContent

cols = []
for column in DataPull.Columns:
    cols.append(str(column))

if("[1 Pre-stress]" in cols and "[2 Post-stress]" in cols):
    columns = ("[1 Pre-stress]", "[2 Post-stress]")
else: 
    if("[1 Pre-stress]" in cols):
        columns = ("[1 Pre-stress]")
    else:
        columns = ("[1 Post-stress]")

vc = RawDataVisualization.As[VisualContent]()
vc.YAxis.Expression = (columns)
```

Alright now the script is working. However, every time I change the parameter of my document property, the script is executed but I think that it checks the table BEFORE the pivot has occurred so it doesn't find the right columns. It only finds the columns that were in the table before the table got a change to update. How do I fix this?

Comment: Why don't you use unpivoted data directly so that visualization doesn't complain if there are missing columns? Is there a specific reason for converting unpivoted data to pivoted?

Comment: I need to pivot the table because once the columns are separated, I have calculated columns that depend on each of the separated columns. It's much easier for me to do calculations this way. That being said, I think I'm getting really close to figuring it out. This is a script I wrote which I assigned to one of my document properties that is used to define a parameter for my sql query.

Comment: If you need to execute the script after the data table loads, this is the method: [link](http://spotfired.blogspot.com/search?q=execcallback)